# How to use one razor view for two action methods but with slightly different contents in some portions only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Suppose two action method is sharing one razor view due to some requirement and assume 99% of this razor view is identical for the both actions except some very miner data.

Now how can i display this minor different data based on the action itself or based on the actionlink, or controller or whatever.

For example, If the controller is "A" and action is "admin" I want to display

```
<p> Welcome Admin </p>
```

And if the controller is "A" and action is "guest" I want to display

```
<p> Welcome Guest</p>
```

Comment: Pass it as part of the `Model` or in `ViewBag`.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290795/asp-net-mvc-can-i-have-one-view-for-multiple-action-methods-to-target-or-do-i-n) shows how to share view between actions... Obviously you know how to pass model to the view and render data from it in the view - so just one duplicate should be enough.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is not what i meant, Is it possible that a razor view identify the action somehow and display some content based on action.. please note that i dont want to have separate razor views for each action? I mean once a razor view is called then there has to be an if() statement inside that razor view to check from which action it is redirected and should display the content based on the action?

Comment: That's a strange requirement and unlikely can be understood from the post by people using ASP.Net MVC... Hope https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+action+name+view will not give you a way (sort of sucks that it is possible... you really should do the right thing and pass model to the view)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no that is not very strange requirement but it seems i'm not able to clearify over comments, is it possilble that we discuss it over chat?

Comment: No. (following text is "unfriendly or unkind" - flag as such): I gave you link how to share single view between actions, how to get action name from the view. I'm not really interested why you have such requirement and simply expressed my opinion about it (I should not have... really should have stopped till you follow information on "what to do if my question closed as duplicate" and [edit] your post... sorry about that all. Good luck).